# BizTalk 2006 Adapter for CRM 4.0 Response

Tags: biztalk, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

HI,

i am using BTS 2006 adapter for MS CRM 4.0 to create records and to fetch data from MS CRM 4.0.
I want to get the response from CRM after the record is created or to fetch data from CRM
For this i am using **response.xsd** coming with BTS 2006 adapter for MS CRM 4.0 to receive response from MS CRM
i set the target namespace for reponse.xsd as: targetNamespace=**"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/BizTalkAdapter/MicrosoftCRM/Response"** according to the organization name here **orgName: "MicrosoftCRM"**
(For more details on this i am referring http://www.ascentium.com/blog/crm/Post398.aspx )

*Now i am getting an error:*

Exception thrown from: segment -1, progress -1
*Inner exception: Received unexpected message type '' **does not match expected type** 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/BizTalkAdapter/MicrosoftCRM/Response#Response'*

Exception type: UnexpectedMessageTypeException
Source: Microsoft.XLANGs.Engine
Target Site: Void VerifyMessage(Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Envelope, System.String, Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Context, Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.OperationInfo)

Here is the Schema instance for response.xsd generated in Visual Studio 2005

```
 - <ns0:Response xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/BizTalkAdapter/MicrosoftCRM/Response">
    - <Header>
      <ReturnCode>ReturnCode_0</ReturnCode>
      <ErrorCode>ErrorCode_0</ErrorCode>
      <ErrorString>ErrorString_0</ErrorString>
      <Retryable>Retryable_0</Retryable>
      </Header>
    - <Body>
      <Message>Message_0</Message>
      </Body>
      </ns0:Response>
```

and this the suspended message details of response from CRM

```
<ns0:Response xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/BizTalkAdapter/MicrosoftCRM/Response">
    <Header>
        <ReturnCode>1</ReturnCode>
        <ErrorCode></ErrorCode>
        <ErrorString></ErrorString>
        <Retryable></Retryable>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <Message><prefix:CreateResponse xmlns:prefix="http://localhost/schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/MicrosoftCRM/CreateResponse"><id>f0650fb5-3ff7-dd11-b0f0-0003ff1a2a3c</id></prefix:CreateResponse></Message>
    </Body>
</ns0:Response>
```

Thanks,

Kuldip

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Microsoft BizTalk CRM 4.0 adapter onwards, use the adapter auto-generated schema 'CRMAdapterResponse_Response.xsd', instead of 'response.xsd'. This schema will be specific to the organization under consideration.

The use of the schema will solve your 'schema does not match expected type' problem.

Thanks.